# Why does the application turn off when I want to get data from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I'm creating a Google Maps App for Android in Kotlin and there is a connection with Firebase used. It crashes during connection with Firebase

I can add data to database, but when I'm trying to download data, app crashes. In database I've got table 'cities', where I keep objects of 'City" type.

```
 private lateinit var citiesList: MutableList<City>
...

 citiesList = mutableListOf()
        var ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("cities")

        ref.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                for ( c in p0.children) {
                    val city  = c.getValue(City::class.java)
                    citiesList.add(city)
                }
            }
```

And City class:

```
class City ( val name: String, val latitude: Double, val longitude: Double)
```

App crashes at this line:

> val city  = c.getValue(City::class.java).

Also, I don't know why type of city value is 'City?', not 'City'. Maybe it's the source of problem. I can't add city to citiesList: `Type mismatch. Required: City, Found: City?`

Comment: Please post also the stack trace from the logical output

Comment: `Class com.example.mapa.City does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped`

Comment: Pelase add the content of  your `City` class and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: I've added @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please change your `City` class from:

```
class City ( val name: String, val latitude: Double, val longitude: Double)
```

to

```
class City (val name: String = "", val latitude: Double = 0.0, val longitude: Double = 0.0)
```

Otherwise you'll get the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Class City does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.

So remember that every field within your `City` class must be initialized in the constructor.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked :) and you're very welcome.